# Why do I keep getting BUILD FAILURE when trying to install ruby 3.1.2 in Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, wsl-2

I've been trying to install ruby 3.1.2 on my ubunutu 20.04 WSL2 setup.

I get through installing rbenv, but when I try to install ruby I get stuck at the downloading ruby stage, and get a BUILD FAILED message.

I'm not sure what other info to provide, but please just ask and I will get anything I'm missing

```
bmcbride@G15:~$ rbenv -v
rbenv 1.2.0-16-gc4395e5
bmcbride@G15:~$ rbenv install 3.1.2 --verbose
/tmp/ruby-build.20220812150245.174.oXyOhQ ~
Downloading ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
error: failed to download ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20220726-1-ga753b24)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20220812150245.174.oXyOhQ
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20220812150245.174.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/ruby-build.20220812150245.174.oXyOhQ ~
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
```

EDIT:

```
RUBY_BUILD_CURL_OPTS="-0 --verbose" rbenv install 3.1.2 --verbose
/tmp/ruby-build.20220812195807.19239.iSYAyi ~
Downloading ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz
*   Trying 151.101.109.178:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2a04:4e42:1a::434:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a04:4e42:1a::434: Network is unreachable
* Connected to cache.ruby-lang.org (151.101.109.178) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [112 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2875 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [300 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [37 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.ruby-lang.org
*  start date: Dec 24 19:42:27 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 25 19:42:26 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "cache.ruby-lang.org" matched cert's "*.ruby-lang.org"
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA H2 2021
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz HTTP/1.0
> Host: cache.ruby-lang.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 20553628
< x-amz-id-2: qUJXy341CDBFg3sNrJh4iAsIj8xlsKtR0W/6qHCp75BYVgRiO21fx6Nh+SEfYbgdaQJWHdyA608=
< x-amz-request-id: 3H67P45YZZZNY8HP
< Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Apr 2022 12:47:13 GMT
< ETag: "3fc61f350eef6c49644eb25f8189874f-3"
< x-amz-version-id: i9hhX3JvclyQw4rFW4_nNjUod9k991xX
< Content-Type: application/x-tar
< Server: AmazonS3
< Via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Age: 1955
< Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2022 11:58:09 GMT
< X-Served-By: cache-iad-kcgs7200133-IAD, cache-tyo11941-TYO
< X-Cache: HIT, HIT
< X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0
< X-Timer: S1660305489.152710,VS0,VE1
<
{ [5 bytes data]

error: failed to download ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20220726-1-ga753b24)
```

EDIT 2

output from forcing rbenv to run ipv4

```
bmcbride@X13:~$ RUBY_BUILD_CURL_OPTS="-4 --verbose" rbenv install 3.1.2 --verbose
/tmp/ruby-build.20220813083713.327.wrSpG1 ~
Downloading ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz
*   Trying 146.75.113.178:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to cache.ruby-lang.org (146.75.113.178) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [106 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2875 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [300 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [37 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.ruby-lang.org
*  start date: Dec 24 19:42:27 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 25 19:42:26 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "cache.ruby-lang.org" matched cert's "*.ruby-lang.org"
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA H2 2021
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x5604c88fa8c0)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz HTTP/2
> Host: cache.ruby-lang.org
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
>
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
} [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 200
< x-amz-id-2: qUJXy341CDBFg3sNrJh4iAsIj8xlsKtR0W/6qHCp75BYVgRiO21fx6Nh+SEfYbgdaQJWHdyA608=
< x-amz-request-id: 3H67P45YZZZNY8HP
< last-modified: Tue, 12 Apr 2022 12:47:13 GMT
< etag: "3fc61f350eef6c49644eb25f8189874f-3"
< x-amz-version-id: i9hhX3JvclyQw4rFW4_nNjUod9k991xX
< content-type: application/x-tar
< server: AmazonS3
< via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
< accept-ranges: bytes
< age: 1122
< date: Sat, 13 Aug 2022 00:37:12 GMT
< x-served-by: cache-iad-kcgs7200103-IAD, cache-nrt-rjtf7700030-NRT
< x-cache: HIT, HIT
< x-cache-hits: 0, 0
< x-timer: S1660351033.733568,VS0,VE1
< content-length: 20553628
<
{ [5 bytes data]
```

Comment: As far as I see there is some problem with `curl` trying to use `HTTP/2`. Try `RUBY_BUILD_CURL_OPTS="--http1.1" rbenv install...` to force curl to use `HTTP/1.1` instead...

Comment: bmcbride@G15:~$ RUBY_BUILD_CURL_OPTS="--http1.1" rbenv install 3.1.2 --verbose
/tmp/ruby-build.20220812180440.19080.4wPUhv ~
Downloading ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz
curl: (18) transfer closed with 15262937 bytes remaining to read
error: failed to download ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz

I tried adding that to the commend and I got a different error but the build still failed.

Comment: You need to understand why `curl` fails, it shouldn't be about guessing, it should be about testing and reading the debug output. Try `RUBY_BUILD_CURL_OPTS="-0 --verbose"` and see what it prints. If still no luck (and no clues in the debug output), force rbenv to use wget instead of curl via `RUBY_BUILD_HTTP_CLIENT=wget` (just ensure it is available) etc...

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov 
I ran that, it says it had a connect fail, that the network is unreachable, I don't know what to do with that info. I posted the full output in an edit on the post

Comment: From the output, I see that it tries to use ipv6 for some reason. I _think_ I heard something about ipv6 issues on WSL2... I don't use WSL at all so I'm not 100% sure it makes sense, but what we could try is to force curl to use ipv4 only. So, could you please try `RUBY_BUILD_CURL_OPTS="-4 --verbose"`?

Comment: I tried both a) RUBY_BUILD_CURL_OPTS="-0 --verbose", and  b) RUBY_BUILD_HTTP_CLIENT=wget and b) actually got the install working. 

It shows as installed with rbenv -versions but ruby -v says ruby command not found. 

I ran rbenv global 3.1.2 as well so I'm not sure what the issue is now

Comment: `rbenv rehash` after installing a new version should help

Answer (score -1):

This may help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

There's a kernel issue that causes big issues when you try to install the new Ruby on WSL.  The above fixes it.